# IE 8 Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, internet-explorer, wordpress-theming

I am pulling hairs here trying to figure out why my Wordpress theme is completely destroyed in IE 8.

It looks and runs fine in all other browsers.  It's almost as if it doesn't even recognize any of the CSS rules as you can see the container element or sizing of elements don't appear to be rendering.

It also doesn't appear to be rendering the slick.js plugin.

If you could please point out what could be causing this entire layout to break in IE 8 it would be very helpful.

http://wirl.alphamediahub.com

Comment: It does that because of the compatibility issues of CSS3 with IE8. Who developed the theme? You? Or you got it from somewhere?

Comment: I found out it was due to me using REM units and not having a pixel fallback for IE 8.  Same with SVG's.